# Is there a way to exclude certain elements using the `in` operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it was possible to figure out if any `<p>` tags are inside the `<header>` or `<footer>` tags on the page using something like this:

```
$("p").each(function() {
  if (!($(this) in $("footer") || $(this) in $("header")) {
    // logic
  }
});
```

My goal is to select the `<p>` tags that are **not** inside the `<header>` or `<footer>`

Comment: [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) can't be used like that, the condition always passes.

Comment: Do you have a class for the content, something like ``main`` tag that would be separated from the footer or header? It would make it much easier for you to select ``p`` tags there.

Comment: Im writing an extension so it is modifying the DOMs of other pages, and there is no guarantee that every page will have `main` tag with the `p` tags I want in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `in` to enumerate jQuery objects. There are other properties and methods in the object which will interfere.

If you want to find the `p` elements which are not in a given container you can use `filter()`:

```
var $p = $('p').filter(function() {
  return $(this).closest('header, footer').length === 0;
});
```

However a simpler method, if possible in your case, would be to structure your HTML so that all the `p` elements you want to target are in a common container. Then your code becomes much more straightforward, for example:

```html
<header>
   <p>Header p</p>
</header>
<main>
   <p>Main p</p>
</main>
<footer>
   <p>Footer p</p>
</footer>
```

```js
var $p = $('main p');
```

Comment: Probably there's nothing interfering, I doubt jQuery object contains `[object Object]` method.

Comment: Probably, yes, but like omitting the radix argument from `parseInt()`, you can more often than not get away with it. But there's that one time where it will just ruin your day. It's best avoided.

Comment: Well, I meant the in operator wouldn't work at all like this, because it converts the first operand to string ...

Comment: Ah, yes in this context it wouldn't work at all. I thought you meant accessing a jQuery object using `in` in general.